# Xamarin project does not work in Release

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My xamarin UWP project works in Debug, but does not work in Release. 
Writing this error:
[image]

I try to add refference to Microsoft.CSharp, But it is not in refference list.
[image]

[image]

Comment: See if you have the `Mono.CSharp.dll` it should be in there

Comment: Where  it it? On screen all available references

Comment: Try one of the other tabs (I can't read) it should be there, or search in the upper-right.

Comment: I check all tabs, and try search but results not found. I added screen search

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev take a look at this thread. There are some manual actions required to make Xamarin.Forms UWP work in Release mode https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57179/uwp-immediate-crash-in-release-mode

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov thanks)